# Command "make:resource" is not defined

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am trying to make resource for my API in Laravel But when I run `php artisan make:resource resourceName`
I get 'error' message

```
Command "make:resource" is not defined.

  Did you mean one of these?
      make:auth
      make:command
      make:controller
      make:event
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:mail
      make:middleware
      make:migration
      make:model
      make:notification
      make:policy
      make:provider
      make:request
      make:seeder
      make:test
```

I've tried to update my composer but it didn't help.
I also checked on my "php artisan list" if `make:resource` command exists, it doesn't.
How do I 'import' that command into my list or is there any way to make resource without that command?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?  `php artisan -V`

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: `php artisan make:resource` was added in Laravel 5.5, that's why you can't find it.